# How can I prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(\frac{nπ}{3})}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2}(6^{1-s}-3^{1-s}-2^{1-s}+1)\zeta(s)$ for $Re(s)>1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Question:-
Prove that

[image]
For $Re(s)>1$

I used this series while evaluating
$\int_{0}^{t} x^2\cot(x)dx$
I got
[image]

Evaluating it we get [image]

On letting $ t=\frac{π}{6}$

We have to find $\int_{0} ^{π/6} x^2 cot(x)dx$ which is equal to [image]

After that I used this for different value of $s$
.But I didn't know how to prove that.

Can anybody help me!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi/3)}{n^s}$$
First of all notice that if $n$ is a multiple of 3 then we have a series of the form:
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(m\pi)}{(3m)^s}=3^{-s}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m^s}=-3^{-s}\eta(s)$$
We now have:
$$S(s)=-3^{-s}\eta(s)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left[(3n-2)\pi/3\right]}{(3n-2)^s}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left[(3n-1)\pi/3\right]}{(3n-1)^s}$$

---

$$\frac{(3n-2)\pi}{3}=n\pi-\frac 23\pi$$
and we can see that:
$$\cos\left(n\pi-\frac23\pi\right)=\cos(n\pi)\cos(2\pi/3)+\sin(n\pi)\sin(2\pi/3)$$
now since $\sin(n\pi)=0$ for an integer $n$ we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left[(3n-2)\pi/3\right]}{(3n-2)^s}=\cos(2\pi/3)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(3n-2)^s}$$
similarly we can say that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left[(3n-1)\pi/3\right]}{(3n-1)^s}=\cos(\pi/3)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(3n-1)^s}$$

---

Bringing this all together we get:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi/3)}{n^s}=-3^{-s}\eta(s)+\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(3n-1)^s}-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(3n-2)^s}$$

Comment: you might also want to check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Generalizations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is a positive integer, and $\operatorname{Re}s>1$ then $$m^{1-s}\zeta(s)=m\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac1{(mn)^s}$$

So we can get the coefficient of $\frac1{n^s}$ in:

$$(6^{1-s}-3 ^{1-s}-2 ^{1-s}+1)\zeta(s)$$

In a case by case basis.

$$\begin{cases}2=6-3-2+1&n\equiv 0\pmod 6\\
-2=-3+1&n\equiv3\pmod 6\\
-1=-2+1&n\equiv 2,4\pmod6\\
1&n\equiv 1,5\pmod 6
\end{cases}$$

But this is the same as $2\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}.$

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could try is re-writing the answer provided, it can be written as:
$${6^{-s}\left(\frac{3^s(1-2^{s-1})}{6^s}+\frac{3(1-2^{s-1})}{6^s}\right)\zeta(s)} {=3(1+3^{s-1})(1-2^{s-1})\zeta(s)=-3(1+3^{s-1})2^{s-1}(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)}$$
$$=-3(1+3^{s-1})2^{s-1}\eta(s)=(6^{s-1}-3^s)\eta(s)$$
$$=(6^{s-1}-3^s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=(3^s-6^{s-1})\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^s}$$
and this form is getting a lot closer to the initial sum

---

we can split the sum up into:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi/3)\cos(2n\pi/3)-\sin(n\pi/3)\sin(2n\pi/3)}{n^s}$$
now you just need to show that:
$$(6^{s-1}-3^s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi/3)\cos(2n\pi/3)-\sin(n\pi/3)\sin(2n\pi/3)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi/3)}{n^s}$$
you can use the fact that:
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)=-\cos\left(\frac{(2n-3)\pi}{6}\right)$$